# What keyboard does Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Gen 2 with AMD Ryzen 4500U have?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, thinkpad, specifications

What keyboard does Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Gen 2 with AMD Ryzen 4500U have?

There are 106 keys (I guess it counts as a 105-key one, the Fn key having some unofficial status).

Lenovo's [Product Specifications Reference](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_E15_Gen_2_AMD/ThinkPad_E15_Gen_2_AMD_Spec.PDF) for this model just says "6-row, spill-resistant, multimedia Fn keys with Unified Communications controls, numeric keypad".

In the Keyboard Settings of Manjaro Settings Manager There are 3 options whose names start with "Lenovo (previously IBM) | ThinkPad":

- Lenovo (previously IBM) | ThinkPad 560Z/600/600E/A22E
- Lenovo (previously IBM) | ThinkPad R60/T60/R61/T61
- Lenovo (previously IBM) | ThinkPad Z60m/Z60t/Z61m/Z61t

So it's probably one of those 12.

One Internet seller gives the part number as LI447-GR, so maybe it's that, but I can't find which of the above it corresponds to.

Images returned by Google and DuckDuckGo searches for some of 560Z, 600, 600E, A22E, R60, T60, R61, T61, Z60m, Z60t, Z61m, Z61t, LI447-GR with "lenovo" and "keyboard" were inconsistent – supposedly the same model looks different on different pages.

Comment: What keyboard the device likely will be entirely based on what region in the world you are in.  Lenovo has similar devices with the same number which only are different to indicate which region of the world they are sold in.  You need to ask Lenovo or your internet seller not us what the keyboard will be for your region.

Comment: It was bought from a Polish reseller of post-leasing laptops. There are indications (like labels glued onto some keycaps) that it was originally German.

Comment: I still fallback to Lenovo is the only one who can answer this question.  LI447-GR suggests it would come with a traditonal 105-key german laptop keyboard.

Comment: I've entered my laptop's serial number at the Lenovo website and it confirms it's German, with Service Part Number 5M10W64625 and Mfg Part SBB0X01882.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `setxkbmap -query` displays `model` as `thinkpadz60`, so I assume it's either Z60m or Z60t.

If anybody knows better, please still contribute information.